# Tickets selling fast VS tickets are selling fast

Tags: ellipsis, headlinese

On the Ryanair website I've seen the message "Tickets selling fast". Should it be "Tickets ARE selling fast"?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that usually the phrase should be "tickets *are* selling fast."

Telegram style is used for short phrases to give them more impact and make the phrase sound more urgent.

The word "selling" here is not a gerund, however, but a [present participle.](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/ing-forms/) They look the same but serve different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. A gerund cannot be used as the only verb in a sentence.

This could be an example of [telegram style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_style).